# rename screenshot with title of article in website using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get all partial screenshots per article from this [website](https://hypebeast.com/search?s=nike%20sacai%20fashion). I succeed in locating the element with below element.

```
<div id="post-4474417" class="post-box    " data-permalink="https://hypebeast.com/2019/1/ten-best-sneakers-paris-fashion-week-fall-winter-2019-runway-shows" data-title="The 10 Best Sneakers From Paris Fashion Week's FW19 Runways">
```

However, when I try renaming the screenshots using `element.text` I just get the same name extracted from the very last element in the website.However when I output with `print(item)`, it gives me all distinct titles. What am I doing wrong here?

Output of `print(item)`:

> - The 10 Best Sneakers From Paris Fashion Week's FW19 Runways
> - sacai Debuts New Nike Sneakers During FW19 Paris Runway Show
> - sacai's Whimsical SS19 Collection Includes a Nike Collaboration

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import os
import time
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Documents/python/Selenium/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://hypebeast.com/search?s=nike+sacai+fashion')
time.sleep(1)
products = [element for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='post-box    ']")))]
element_item = [element.text for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h2/span")))]
for item in element_item:
    print(item)

i = 1
for product in products:
    location = product.location_once_scrolled_into_view

    size = product.size
    png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png() 
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(png)) 

    left = location['x']
    top = location['y']
    right = location['x'] + size['width']
    bottom = location['y'] + size['height']
    im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)).save(str(i)+"_"+item+".png")
    i=i+1
    if not product :
        pass

sleep(randint(1,2))

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)).save(str(i)+"_"+item+".png")
```

This will return you last value because when you iterate the loop at the end of the loop you will get last value only.

Since you already have list values inside the list element `element_item` you can use that list inside the next for loop like that.

```
i = 1
for product in products:

 im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)).save(str(i)+"_"+ element_item[i-1] +".png")

 i=i+1
```

Comment: Hi Kunduk thank you very much your code it worked! Appreciate the help